# How to compile and use GDAL with gpu support(OpenCL)?

Tags: python, c++, opencl, gdal

I try to compile latest Gdal on Ubuntu 16 with Nvidia GeForce 1060 (Cuda toolkit 10 is installed). Also i install package nvidia-opencl-dev via apt-get for opencl headers

```
./configure --with-python=python3 --with-spatialite --with-pg --with-cryptopp --with-curl --with-opencl=yes --with-proj=/usr/local --prefix=/usr  --with-opencl-include="/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/include/CL/" --with-opencl-lib="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1 -lOpenCL"
```

All path to files and dirs are correct

After configuration, I checked OpenCL support
OpenCL support:            yes

Compiler didn't show me errors. All it seemed well.

But when I began to execute commands, no switching to the video card occurs
I tried this way

```
time gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 1.tif 2.tif   --debug on
```

and this

```
time gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 1.tif 3.tif -wo USE_OPENCL=TRUE  --debug on
```

Nvidia-smi showed that the gpu is not used at all. No usage information OpenCL in debug output.
Same story with another commands. Also i tried gdal2tiles.py - no acceleration and usage of gpu.

A couple of years ago I compiled Gdal with gpu and gdal2tiles.py worked much faster with opencl.

I really hope that someone will share the experience of compilation and using gdal with gpu.

Answer (score 1):

Not all GDAL raster methods will use OpenCL. If I do the same example as you did, in my GDAL compiled with OpenCL, I don't have any OpenCL usage reported.

```sh
time gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 001972Argb_12.tif x.tif -wo USE_OPENCL=TRUE -wt Float32 --debug on
```

The output:

```
(...)
80GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKNearestNoMasksOrDstDensityOnlyFloat() Src=3987,7505,2012x1260 Dst=4005,7529,2002x1255
.GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKNearestNoMasksOrDstDensityOnlyFloat() Src=5994,7511,2006x1260 Dst=6007,7529,2003x1255
.GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKNearestNoMasksOrDstDensityOnlyFloat() Src=0,8746,1980x1254 Dst=0,8784,2002x1255
.90GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKNearestNoMasksOrDstDensityOnlyFloat() Src=1975,8752,2013x1248 Dst=2002,8784,2003x1255
.GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKNearestNoMasksOrDstDensityOnlyFloat() Src=3983,8759,2012x1241 Dst=4005,8784,2002x1255
.GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKNearestNoMasksOrDstDensityOnlyFloat() Src=5991,8764,2009x1236 Dst=6007,8784,2003x1255
.100 - done.
GDAL: Flushing dirty blocks: 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
GDAL: GDALClose(x.tif, this=0x55f28d7cf530)
GDAL: GDALClose(001972Argb_12.tif, this=0x55f28d5a2b90)
DGNv8: Driver cleanup

real    0m2,411s
user    0m1,972s
sys 0m0,440s
```

But if I request a `bicubic` resampling of the raster, for example, OpenCL is used.

```sh
time gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 001972Argb_12.tif x.tif -wo USE_OPENCL=TRUE -wt Float32 --debug on -r cubic
```

The output:

```
(...)
80OpenCL: Found vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
OpenCL: Connected to vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKOpenCLCase() Src=5992,7509,2008x1264 Dst=6007,7529,2003x1255
.OpenCL: Found vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
OpenCL: Connected to vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKOpenCLCase() Src=0,8744,1982x1256 Dst=0,8784,2002x1255
.OpenCL: Found vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
OpenCL: Connected to vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKOpenCLCase() Src=1973,8750,2017x1250 Dst=2002,8784,2003x1255
.90OpenCL: Found vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
OpenCL: Connected to vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKOpenCLCase() Src=3981,8757,2016x1243 Dst=4005,8784,2002x1255
.OpenCL: Found vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
OpenCL: Connected to vendor='NVIDIA Corporation' / device='GeForce GTX 950M' (GPU implementation).
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKOpenCLCase() Src=5989,8762,2011x1238 Dst=6007,8784,2003x1255
..100 - done.
GDAL: Flushing dirty blocks: 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
GDAL: GDALClose(x.tif, this=0x562582674c60)
GDAL: GDALClose(001972Argb_12.tif, this=0x562582448bc0)
DGNv8: Driver cleanup

real    0m6,732s
user    0m3,563s
sys 0m3,088s
```

In the debug log it is clear that, for the resampling requested, the OpenCL is used.